# Jenkins switch user and execute command

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to switch user in my Jenkinsfile and then run a command. Running it on the Linux box this command does work, however when running it in Jenkins I get the following error:

```
su: unrecognized option '--stop'
Try `su --help' for more information.
```

The command I wish to execute:

```
su - testuser -c 'testcontrol --stop --app testfeed --no_prompt_on_change'
```

My Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
  echo 'Stopping Feed'
  CHEF_SERVER = sh (script: 'grep chef_server_url /etc/chef/client.rb | awk -F\'/\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
  TARGET_SERVER = "foo"
  stage('Switching userstopping process') {
    try {
        echo sh(script: "ssh ${CHEF_SERVER} salt ${TARGET_SERVER} cmd.run \\'su - testuser -c 'testcontrol --stop --app testfeed --no_prompt_on_change'\\'", returnStdout: true)
    }
    catch (e) {
        // catch error code here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try shoving the stuff in that script command into a file. it seems like you're doing a bunch of escaping that you can probably mostly avoid if you just do `sh './switch_userstopping_process.sh'`. that way you can also run your script outside of jenkins to make sure it works.

from a talk at Jenkins World 2016, [No, You Shouldn't Do That!
Lessons from Using Pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/sites/default/files/2016-jenkins-world-no_you_shouldnt_do_that_lessons_from_using_pipeline.pdf): "Put build logic in external scripts if possible"

you can just as easily `echo` in a shell script, and you'll have an easier time implementing the part where you grab the `CHEF_SERVER`, temporary store it in a groovy variable, and then use it in another shell script. in fact, here's your whole pipeline:

```
node {
  sh './switch_userstopping_process.sh'
}
```

i'm not sure what exactly you had in mind for the catch logic. maybe that stays. enjoy pipelines!